# Model is skipping 'validate' inconsistently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

Using Rails 4/Mongoid, I have a model called `MyClass` with a validation defined as:

```
class MyClass
  include Mongoid::Document

  ...some attributes...

  before_validation :prevalidate

  def prevalidate
    self.required_prop = false if self.required_prop_two
  end
  validate do |instance|
    puts 'VALIDATING'
    ...some more validation...
  end
end
```

Then I have two Rspec tests, only one of which prints 'VALIDATING':

```
# This test fails, and does not print 'VALIDATING'
it 'is an invalid instance' do
  instance = Fabricate.build(:my_class)
  instance.required_prop = nil
  instance.required_prop_two = nil
  instance.should have(1).errors_on(:required_props)
end
# This test passes, and prints 'VALIDATING'
it 'is a valid instance' do
  instance = Fabricate.build(:my_class)
  instance.other_required_prop = nil
  instance.should have(1).errors_on(:other_required_prop)
end
```

I'm under the assumption that `validate` should always run when checking these errors. However, it *only* runs in Test #2 and *never* for Test #1, and I'm completely boggled as to how this could be skipped. It seems to be related to setting that second property, as when the second is commented out, Test #1 runs `validate`.

I know my example is sparse, but does anyone have a suggestion how something like this could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, turns out I shot myself in the foot over my usage of the `before_validation` clause: because my last evaluated line in `prevalidate` returned false, it aborted validation.

```
def prevalidate
  self.required_prop = false if self.some_other_prop
  return true # Otherwise, it'll stop validation
end
```

Sometimes the Ruby way of returning the last evaluation burns me on stuff like this.